# Kubernetes python API get instances of CRD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-custom-resources, kubernetes-python-client

I'm currently using the Python APIs for Kubernetes and I have to:

- Retrieve the instance of a custom resource name `FADepl`.
- Edit the value of that instance.

In the terminal, I would simply list all `FADepls` with `kubectl get fadepl` and then edit the right one using `kubectl edit fadepl <fadepl_name>`. I checked the [K8s APIs for Python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md) but I can't find what I need. Is it something I can do with the APIs?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. Using [**`get_namespaced_custom_object`**](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md#get_namespaced_custom_object) you can retrieve the instance. This method returns a namespace scoped custom object. By default it uses a synchronous HTTP request.

Since the output of that method returns an object, you can simply replace it using [**`replace_cluster_custom_object`**](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md#replace_cluster_custom_object).

[Here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/?CodeExample=replace+namespaced+custom+object) you can find implementation examples.

See also whole list of [API Reference for Python](https://aiokubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [list_cluster_custom_object](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md#list_cluster_custom_object) method from [kubernetes.client.CustomObjectsApi](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md#kubernetesclientcustomobjectsapi).

Let's say that I need to get all calico [globalnetworksets](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/reference/resources/networkset) instances which are a CRD from calico project.

So first, we need to retrieve some crd data using kubectl as follows:

```bash
# get api group, version and plural

> kubectl api-resources -o wide | grep globalnetworkset
    globalnetworksets  crd.projectcalico.org/v1  false  GlobalNetworkSet
     ---------------    -------------------  --
        `plural`             api group       v
```

With that in mind, we implement `list_cluster_custom_object`

```py
from kubernetes.client import CustomObjectsApi

group = "crd.projectcalico.org"
v = "v1"
plural = "globalnetworksets"

global_network_sets = CustomObjectsApi.list_cluster_custom_object(group, v, plural)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the [get_namespaced_custom_object](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md#get_namespaced_custom_object) call that should do the trick